# AngularJS application hosted on Github pages (gh-pages) ajax crawling

Tags: ajax, angularjs, github, search-engine

anyone knows if is possible to make an AngularJS with client-side navigation crawlable by search engines if it is hosted on Github?

Let's say, my application has 3 client-side urls:

- http : //my-example-application.com/#!/home
- http : //my-example-application.com/#!/documentation
- http : //my-example-application.com/#!/download

These URL's will not be seen by the search engines because they are served on the client side, but according to [Google Ajax applications recommendations to help search engines](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) the dynamic content generated by a javascript application could be cached previously, so the crawlers would search for a cached version of the previous pages on these URL's:

- http : //my-example-application.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/home
- http : //my-example-application.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/documentation
- http : //my-example-application.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/download

This could be accomplished via url rewriting on a web server, but do we have any alternative if we are hosting the dynamic page on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BromBone (http://www.brombone.com/) claims to offer that _escaped_fragment_ handling as a service for you. However, it's a commercial service. I guess it would matter how important it was to you for those pages to work with Google.